# Solidity mapping multiple items to one user

Tags: solidity, nodejs

i'm trying to assign array of items to one user and i want to put address to mapping function and get all items like that:

```
mapping(address => Item[]) public ownerToItems;
```

but there is problem with assignment, first time accessing this array will be empty. How example like this should be build?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function add(address owner, uint arg1, uint arg2, uint arg3) external {
    ownerToItems[owner].push(Item(arg1, arg2, arg3));
}
```

Comment: This is good, can you also tell me how to returns this items to read all in front-end? In solidity we can't returns array so what it should looks like?

Comment: Just to correct that bit of (common) misinformation, you can return arrays from your smart contract. You're probably thinking about the ABI encoder's limitation around returning nested arrays/structs.

Comment: You can easily return the items one at a time. (In fact, because of your public declaration, clients should already be able to call `ownerToItems(address addr, uint256 index)`. You probably want to add a `view` function that returns `ownerToItems[addr].length` to make enumeration easier on the client.